# Coffeescript and Backbone.js + linting issue with grunt.js

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm having a bit of an issue with a class extending the Backbone.Model.

Using the following class …

```
class Turtles extends Backbone.Model

    idAttribute: "_id"
    legs: [0,1,3,5]
    urlRoot: '/turtles'

module.exports = Turtles
```

grunt.js is throwing this error when linting.

```
[L21:C18] 'Turtles' is already defined.
    function Turtles() {
```

The output of the compile js file looks like this:

```
(function() {
  var Turtles,
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

  Turtles = (function(_super) {

    __extends(Turtles, _super);

    function Turtles() {
      return Turtles.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Turtles.prototype.idAttribute = "_id";

    Turtles.prototype.points = [0, 1, 3, 5];

    Turtles.prototype.categories = ['story', 'tech', 'design', 'bug'];

    Turtles.prototype.urlRoot = '/cards';

    return Turtles;

  })(Backbone.Model);

  module.exports = Turtles;

}).call(this);
```

This output is very similar to some views I have extended using `class Application extends Backbone.View`, so I'm not sure why this model would be failing linting when all my views and collections arent.

That all being said, replacing `class Turtles extends Backbone.Model` with `Turtles = Backbone.Model.extend` works find and causes no errors.

Just wondered if anyone has had experience with this before, or perhaps can spot an issue.

Thanks